# Why does &i32 sometimes implement Unpin and sometimes not?

Tags: rust

```rust
use std::pin::Pin;

fn main() {
    let val: i32 = 3;

    let val_pin = Pin::new(&val);
    f(val_pin);

    f(Pin::new(&val));
}

fn f(_val: Pin<&dyn TestTrait>) {}

trait TestTrait {}

impl TestTrait for i32 {}
```

Line 9 `f(Pin::new(&val));` throws a compiler error, but line 6 `let val_pin = Pin::new(&val);` does not. The compiler error is:

```
error[E0277]: `dyn TestTrait` cannot be unpinned
   --> src/main.rs:9:7
    |
9   |     f(Pin::new(&val));
    |       ^^^^^^^^ the trait `Unpin` is not implemented for `dyn TestTrait`
    |
    = note: consider using `Box::pin`
note: required by a bound in `Pin::<P>::new`
   --> /usr/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/pin.rs:482:23
    |
482 | impl<P: Deref<Target: Unpin>> Pin<P> {
    |                       ^^^^^ required by this bound in `Pin::<P>::new`
```

So it seems that the trait `Unpin` is implemented for `&val` in line 6, but not in line 9. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with some subtleties of type inference.

The variable on line 6 is inferred to be `Pin<&i32>` which later gets automatically upcast to `Pin<&dyn TestTrait>` on line 7.  You can check this by inserting the following assignment after line 6, which forces a compile-time error that shows you the type of `my_val`:

```
let _: () = my_val;
```

```
  = note: expected unit type `()`
                found struct `Pin<&i32>`
```

(Side note: this won't work if `my_val` has type `()` -- then the assignment will succeed!)

In contrast, when you create the `Pin` as a temporary on line 9, it is inferred to be `Pin<&dyn TestTrait>` instead of `Pin<&i32>`, and `&dyn TestTrait` doesn't implement `Unpin` by default.

You can fix this by explicitly specifying the type argument `T` of `Pin<T>` to be `&i32` on line 9:

```
f(Pin::<&i32>::new(&val));
```

You could also fix this by specifying a bound on `TypeTrait` of `Unpin`, which will cause `&dyn TestTrait` to implement `Unpin` as well:

```
trait TestTrait: Unpin {}
```

Finally, you could also fix the issue by changing `f` to accept `Pin<&impl TestTrait>` instead of `Pin<&dyn TestTrait>`:

```
fn f(_val: Pin<&impl TestTrait>) {}
```

---

As pointed out by @KevinReid, you can also indicate that the trait object must implement `Unpin`, which is allowed because `Unpin` has no methods:

```
fn f(_val: Pin<&(dyn TestTrait + Unpin)>) {}
```

Comment: A fourth way: `&(dyn TestTrait + Unpin)`. Since `Unpin` is a marker trait with no methods, you can specify it in `dyn` just like the more commonly seen `+ Send + Sync`.

Comment: @KevinReid Right, I always forget you can do that with marker traits.